# iptables blocking remote MySQL connection

Tags: linux, mysql, iptables

I'm trying to set my server (CentOS 6.9) to accept remote MySQL connections and I'm stuck on the firewall config

I have everything set right on the MySQL side. I can connect through telnet if I stop iptables, but not when it's active

I've already tried:

```
-A INPUT -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
```

But still I get "connection refused" with iptables active. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: output of iptables -L -x -v -n

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:3306 
      11     1122 acctboth   all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
       5      372 tcpchk     tcp  --  !lo    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
       6      750 udpchk     udp  --  !lo    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
       0        0 icmpchk    icmp --  !lo    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
      11     1122 ipdrop_global  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
      11     1122 input_custom  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
       0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
       0        0 ssh        tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:22022 
       0        0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 8 limit: up to 2/sec burst 10 mode srcip 
       0        0 LOG        icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 8 limit: avg 5/min burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 3 prefix `ICMP_DROP ' 
       0        0 DROP       icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 8                                                                                                                                                                      
       0        0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 0                                                                                                                                                                      
       0        0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 3 code 4                                                                                                                                                               
       0        0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 3 code 3                                                                                                                                                               
       0        0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 3 code 1                                                                                                                                                               
       0        0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 11                                                                                                                                                                     
       0        0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 12                                                                                                                                                                     
       0        0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 30                                                                                                                                                                     
       0        0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state ESTABLISHED                                                                                                                                                                
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       103.21.244.0/22      0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80                                                                                                                                                                       
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       103.22.200.0/22      0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80                                                                                                                                                                       
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       103.31.4.0/22        0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80                                                                                                                                                                       
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       104.16.0.0/12        0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80                                                                                                                                                                       
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       108.162.192.0/18     0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80                                                                                                                                                                       
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       131.0.72.0/22        0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80                                                                                                                                                                       
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       141.101.64.0/18      0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80                                                                                                                                                                       
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       162.158.0.0/15       0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80                                                                                                                                                                       
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       172.64.0.0/13        0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80                                                                                                                                                                       
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       173.245.48.0/20      0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80                                                                                                                                                                       
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       188.114.96.0/20      0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80                                                                                                                                                                       
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       190.93.240.0/20      0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80                                                                                                                                                                       
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       197.234.240.0/22     0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80                                                                                                                                                                       
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       198.41.128.0/17      0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80                                                                                                                                                                       
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       216.172.173.146      0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80                                                                                                                                                                       
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       198.1.121.202        0.0.0.0/0           multiport dports 22,80 
       0        0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       198.1.121.202        0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 8 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       184.173.226.84       0.0.0.0/0           multiport dports 22,80 
       0        0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       184.173.226.84       0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 8 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       184.172.224.50       0.0.0.0/0           multiport dports 22,80 
       0        0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       184.172.224.50       0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 8 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:53 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:21 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:22 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:25 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:26 
       0        0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:53 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:110 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:143 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:443 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:465 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:587 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:2082 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:2083 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:2084 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:2086 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:2087 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:2089 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:2222 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:2095 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:2096 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:993 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:995 
       0        0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       8.8.4.4              0.0.0.0/0           udp spt:53 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       8.8.4.4              0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:53 
       6      750 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       8.8.8.8              0.0.0.0/0           udp spt:53 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       8.8.8.8              0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:53 
       5      372 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:22022 
       0        0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:22022 
       0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
       0        0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           limit: avg 1/sec burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix `LOG_INPUT: ' 
       0        0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:3306 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:3306 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       216.172.173.146      0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:3306 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       216.172.173.146      0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:3306 

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
       0        0 tcpchk     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
       0        0 udpchk     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
       0        0 icmpchk    icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
      10      866 cpanel-dovecot-solr  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
      10      866 acctboth   all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
       4      432 tcpchk     tcp  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
       6      434 udpchk     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
       0        0 icmpchk    icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
      10      866 output_custom  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
       0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      lo      0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
       0        0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW,ESTABLISHED 
       0        0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            198.1.121.202       icmp type 0 
       0        0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            184.173.226.84      icmp type 0 
       0        0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            184.172.224.50      icmp type 0 
       0        0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:1129 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:1129 
       0        0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:30000 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:30000 
       0        0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:110 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:110 
       0        0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:43 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:43 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:873 
       0        0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           owner UID match 0 
       0        0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
       0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      lo      0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:21 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:22 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            74.52.223.18        tcp dpt:25 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            74.52.223.66        tcp dpt:25 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            64.5.52.7           tcp dpt:25 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            64.5.52.8           tcp dpt:25 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            64.5.52.9           tcp dpt:25 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            64.5.52.12          tcp dpt:25 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            64.5.52.13          tcp dpt:25 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            64.5.52.14          tcp dpt:25 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            67.18.137.84        tcp dpt:25 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            67.18.137.85        tcp dpt:25 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            67.18.137.86        tcp dpt:25 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            67.18.137.87        tcp dpt:25 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            67.18.137.88        tcp dpt:25 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            74.52.222.226       tcp dpt:25 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            74.52.222.242       tcp dpt:25 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            74.52.223.2         tcp dpt:25 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:25 owner UID match 47 
       0        0 LOG        tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           ! owner UID match 0 multiport dports 25,465,587 limit: avg 1/sec burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 5 prefix `OUTBOUND-SMTP : ' 
       6      434 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:53 ! owner UID match 99 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:53 ! owner UID match 99 
       0        0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            8.8.4.4             udp dpt:53 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            8.8.4.4             tcp dpt:53 
       0        0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            8.8.8.8             udp dpt:53 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            8.8.8.8             tcp dpt:53 
       0        0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:53 owner UID match 99 limit: avg 20/sec burst 5 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:53 owner UID match 99 limit: avg 20/sec burst 5 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:443 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:465 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:587 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:2086 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:2087 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:2089 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:3306 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:37 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:2703 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:53 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:21 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:22 
       4      432 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:22022 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:25 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:26 
       0        0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp spt:53 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:80 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:110 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:143 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:443 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:465 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:587 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:2082 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:2083 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:2084 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:2086 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:2087 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:2089 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:2222 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:2095 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:2096 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:993 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:995 
       0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
       0        0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           limit: avg 1/sec burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix `LOG_OUTPUT: ' 
       0        0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:3306 

Chain acctboth (2 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain cpanel-dovecot-solr (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           multiport sports 8984,7984 owner UID match 490 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           multiport sports 8984,7984 owner UID match 0 
       0        0 REJECT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           multiport sports 8984,7984 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable 

Chain icmpchk (3 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain input_custom (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ipdrop_global (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
       0        0 DROP       all  --  *      *       43.255.190.0/23      0.0.0.0/0           

Chain output_custom (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ssh (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
       0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       67.18.2.226          0.0.0.0/0           
       0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       50.23.47.206         0.0.0.0/0           
       0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       70.87.80.194         0.0.0.0/0           
       0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       216.106.185.169      0.0.0.0/0           
       0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       12.96.160.0/24       0.0.0.0/0           
       0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       216.19.0.0/24        0.0.0.0/0           
       0        0            tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW recent: SET name: DEFAULT side: source 
       0        0 LOG        tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW recent: CHECK seconds: 60 hit_count: 10 name: DEFAULT side: source limit: avg 10/min burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 5 prefix `SSH-ATTACK : ' 
       0        0 REJECT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW recent: UPDATE seconds: 60 hit_count: 10 name: DEFAULT side: source reject-with tcp-reset 
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain tcpchk (3 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain udpchk (3 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I stop iptables" and "when it's active" ? how are you stopping/activating iptables ?

Comment: service iptables start and service iptables stop

Comment: -I INPUT 1 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-I OUTPUT 1 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
After you make this change wait 10 min, and do **iptables -L -x -v -n** post results.  Major rewrites ahead of you.

Comment: Do you have ipset installed or can you install it?

Comment: I dont have it but I could install it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see that "-A INPUT -j DROP" line ? That'll drop any traffic on the input chain before it reaches your mysql rules, as rules are read from top to bottom. The -A means append, so any rules after that are put after the one that drops everything, hence those ones never match any traffic.

You have a similar issue on your OUTPUT chain also. You're options are a) use -P DROP on the chain, which'll default it to drop as the last action if no others match (and remove the rule you have now), or b) put that rule last so it's appended after all others. You an also use -I for insert (which'll put the rule first) rather than -A but that's kinda confusing to mix with -A imho.

Comment: ok, it worked by removing those 2 lines: -A INPUT -j DROP 
and -A OUTPUT -j DROP. First I tried moving it to the end of the file, but nothing changed. Only after commenting both, then it worked. But now, am I safe with these rules? anyway, thank you so much for your help

Comment: you cant just move it to the end of the file as that file is in sections. The 'raw', 'filter', 'mangle' etc, those are all different sections. You'd want to move them to the end of the rules for that particular table (input or output) but in the same section (filter).

Comment: @diogo.abdalla   You may not be safe by just removing the DROP.  You need to test it.  Try connecting to services that shouldn't be allowed to be connected to, if it works you have a problem.  Maybe even use nessus to scan your computer.